# CSS Saturate Filter on Canvas

Tags: css, canvas, css-filters

I have a canvas which is currently drawing a grey scale diagram ([JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/tugowiwiqa/1/edit?html,css,js,output)).

It's effectively a radial progress meter, that will be used a lot in the application. However, rather than colouring it with Javascript, I'd prefer to be able to give it a colour based on a class.

I thought it would be an ideal use case for CSS filters. I'd draw the default progress meter in gray, then use CSS filters to add saturation and do a hue rotation, in order to achieve blue, orange and green too.

```
canvas {
  -webkit-filter: saturate(8);
}
```

The rule was supported and valid in Chrome, but the problem was, it doesn't seem to change the saturation at all.

I'm imagining that `#aaa` is transformed into it's HSL counterpart `hsl(0, 0%, 67%)`. Then when I increase the saturation with a filter, it should become more saturated, but for the same hue.

I was hoping to end up with something like `hsl(0, 50%, 67%)` but instead, the filter doesn't seem to change the colour at all, no matter what value I use.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you change  #aaa to it's corresponding hsl value hsl(0, 11.1%, 70%) it does change...

Comment: `#aaa` is a grey shade, which means that its hsl value has no saturation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out if you draw the meter with some saturation initially, you can use the `hue-rotate` filter and then you can desaturate them to achieve grey scale again.

http://jsbin.com/qohokivobo/2/edit?html,css,output

Conceptually, this isn't an answer. But in the meantime, it's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about picking the color from the CSS style ?

```
canvas {
  color: red;
}


function init() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('test'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let style = window.getComputedStyle (canvas);
  let color = style.color;
  canvas.width = 300;
  canvas.height = 300;

  let x = canvas.width / 2,
      y = canvas.height / 2;

  context.beginPath( );
  context.arc(x, y, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.lineWidth = 20;
  context.stroke();

  context.globalAlpha = 0.85;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 100, 0, Math.PI + 0.3, false);
  context.strokeStyle = '#eee';
  context.stroke();

}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/bizaziheyo/1/)